# Chomping left, right string by whitespace to iterate regex matches

Tags: python, string, substring, difflib

The goal is to extract the matching "words" (bounded by `\b|$|\s`), given the difflib `SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks()` output, e.g. given:

> s1 = "HYC00 Schulrucksack Damen, Causal Travel Schultaschen 14 Zoll Laptop Rucksack für Mädchen im Teenageralter Leichter Rucksack Wasserabweisend Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack"

> s2 = "HYC00 School Backpack Women, Causal Travel School Bags 14 Inch Laptop Backpack for Teenage Girls Lightweight Backpack Water-Repellent Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack"

The expected matching blocks to extract are:

```
['HYC00', 'Causal Travel', '14', 'Laptop', 'Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack']
```

The simple cases are when the matching blocks from the difflib are immediately bounded by `\b|$|\s`, e.g.

```
import re
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

s1 = "HYC00 Schulrucksack Damen, Causal Travel Schultaschen 14 Zoll Laptop Rucksack für Mädchen im Teenageralter Leichter Rucksack Wasserabweisend Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack"

s2 = "HYC00 School Backpack Women, Causal Travel School Bags 14 Inch Laptop Backpack for Teenage Girls Lightweight Backpack Water-Repellent Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack"

def is_substring_a_phrase(substring, s1):
  if substring:
    # Check if matching substring is bounded by word boundary.
    match = re.findall(rf"\b{substring}(?=\s|$)", s1)
    if match: 
      return match[0]

def matcher(s1, s2):
  x = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
  for m in x.get_matching_blocks():
    # Extract the substring.
    full_substring = s1[m.a:m.a+m.size].strip()
    match = is_substring_a_phrase(full_substring, s1)
    if match:
      yield match
      continue

matcher(s1, s2)
```

[out]:

```
['14', 'Laptop', 'Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack']
```

Then to capture the `HYC00` and `Causal Travel`, the matching blocks are respectively `HYC00 Sch` and `men, Causual Travel`, so we'll have to do some "chomping" and remove the left, right or left and right most partial "words", i.e.

```
def matcher(s1, s2):
  x = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
  for m in x.get_matching_blocks():
    # Extract the substring.
    full_substring = s1[m.a:m.a+m.size].strip()
    match = is_substring_a_phrase(full_substring, s1)
    if match:
      yield match
      continue

    # Extract the left chomp substring.
    left = " ".join(s1[m.a:m.a+m.size].strip().split()[1:])
    match = is_substring_a_phrase(left, s1)
    if match:
      yield match
      continue


    # Extract the right chomp substring.
    right = " ".join(s1[m.a:m.a+m.size].strip().split()[:-1])
    match = is_substring_a_phrase(right, s1)
    if match:
      yield match
      continue


    # Extract the right chomp substring.
    leftright = " ".join(s1[m.a:m.a+m.size].strip().split()[1:-1])
    match = is_substring_a_phrase(leftright, s1)
    if match:
      yield match
      continue

matcher(s1, s2)
```

[out]:

```
['HYC00',
 'Causal Travel',
 '14',
 'Laptop',
 'Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack']
```

While the code snippet above works as expected, my questions in parts:

- is there some way to avoid the repeated code for the various chomp and multiple if-else to extract the matching blocks bounded by `\b|$|\s`?
- is there a direct way to specify in `.get_matching_blocks()` to get only the parts bounded by `\b|$|\s`?
- is there other ways of achieving the same objective without using the get_matching_blocks in this messy manner?

Comment: You could instead first break the two texts into words according to your seperator, and then use `SequenceMatcher` on the two lists of words.

Answer (score 1):

From @megaing's comment

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

s1 = "HYC00 Schulrucksack Damen, Causal Travel Schultaschen 14 Zoll Laptop Rucksack für Mädchen im Teenageralter Leichter Rucksack Wasserabweisend Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack"

s2 = "HYC00 School Backpack Women, Causal Travel School Bags 14 Inch Laptop Backpack for Teenage Girls Lightweight Backpack Water-Repellent Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack"


x = SequenceMatcher(None, s1.split(), s2.split())

for m in x.get_matching_blocks():
    # Extract the substring.
    full_substring = " ".join(s1.split()[m.a:m.a+m.size])
    print(full_substring)
```

[out]:

```
HYC00
Causal Travel
14
Laptop
Bookbag College Boys Men Work Daypack
```